# Kubernetes kube-dns not resolving

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes

I am noticing an unusual high latency when trying to resolve local and external DNS lookups inside Kubernetes. `nslookup` requests are sometimes resolved but take on average 40 seconds to complete.

These lookups are causing systems like Kafka and Mariadb to crash: `Timed out waiting for connection while in state: CONNECTING`

I have included below a successful and unsuccessful `nslookup` of `kubernetes.default`

```sh
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
0.1851s   Server:    10.39.240.10
0.0004s   Address 1: 10.39.240.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.localbe-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
35.2081s  command terminated with exit code 1
0.0075s   nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'
0.0004s   

Total   35.4025s
```

```sh
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox -- nslookup kubernetes.default
0.1362s    Server:    10.39.240.10
0.1370s    Address 1: 10.39.240.10 kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.localbe-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
25.1734s                                                                              
40.2251s   Name:      kubernetes.defaultnetes.default
40.2288s   Address 1: 10.39.240.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local240.1 kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
40.2291s   

Total   40.2292s
```

I have tried [adjusting](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#configure-stub-domain-and-upstream-dns-servers) the KubeDNS configuration map, rebuild/add new nodes to the cluster, scaling up the amount of available kube-dns instances all without any success.

Only when inspecting the kube-dns logs did I find something interesting. The `kubedns` container inside `kube-dns` threw the following warning:

`Could not find endpoints for service "mariadb" in namespace "mysql". DNS records will be created once endpoints show up.`

```sh
$ kubectl logs -n kube-system kube-dns-b46cc9485-qjm25 -c kubedns
I0603 22:23:48.889404       1 dns.go:48] version: 1.14.13
I0603 22:23:48.890627       1 server.go:69] Using configuration read from directory: /kube-dns-config with period 10s
I0603 22:23:48.890762       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --alsologtostderr="false"
I0603 22:23:48.890774       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --config-dir="/kube-dns-config"
I0603 22:23:48.890794       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --config-map=""
I0603 22:23:48.890798       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --config-map-namespace="kube-system"
I0603 22:23:48.890802       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --config-period="10s"
I0603 22:23:48.890809       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --dns-bind-address="0.0.0.0"
I0603 22:23:48.890820       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --dns-port="10053"
I0603 22:23:48.890827       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --domain="cluster.local."
I0603 22:23:48.890839       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --federations=""
I0603 22:23:48.890851       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --healthz-port="8081"
I0603 22:23:48.890856       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --initial-sync-timeout="1m0s"
I0603 22:23:48.890865       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --kube-master-url=""
I0603 22:23:48.890875       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --kubecfg-file=""
I0603 22:23:48.890880       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --log-backtrace-at=":0"
I0603 22:23:48.890893       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --log-dir=""
I0603 22:23:48.890898       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --log-flush-frequency="5s"
I0603 22:23:48.890910       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --logtostderr="true"
I0603 22:23:48.890914       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --nameservers=""
I0603 22:23:48.890918       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --stderrthreshold="2"
I0603 22:23:48.890922       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --v="2"
I0603 22:23:48.890932       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --version="false"
I0603 22:23:48.890944       1 server.go:121] FLAG: --vmodule=""
I0603 22:23:48.891109       1 server.go:169] Starting SkyDNS server (0.0.0.0:10053)
I0603 22:23:48.891471       1 server.go:179] Skydns metrics enabled (/metrics:10055)
I0603 22:23:48.891514       1 dns.go:188] Starting endpointsController
I0603 22:23:48.891523       1 dns.go:191] Starting serviceController
I0603 22:23:48.891765       1 sync.go:167] Updated stubDomains to map[acme.local:[1.2.3.4]]
I0603 22:23:48.891794       1 sync.go:177] Updated upstreamNameservers to [8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4]
I0603 22:23:48.891836       1 dns.go:184] Configuration updated: {TypeMeta:{Kind: APIVersion:} Federations:map[] StubDomains:map[acme.local:[1.2.3.4]] UpstreamNameservers:[8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4]}
I0603 22:23:48.892030       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for tcp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0603 22:23:48.892059       1 logs.go:41] skydns: ready for queries on cluster.local. for udp://0.0.0.0:10053 [rcache 0]
I0603 22:23:48.905592       1 dns.go:601] Could not find endpoints for service "broker" in namespace "kafka". DNS records will be created once endpoints show up.
I0603 22:23:48.905640       1 dns.go:601] Could not find endpoints for service "prometheus-alertmanager-operated" in namespace "metrics". DNS records will be created once endpoints show up.
I0603 22:23:48.905825       1 dns.go:601] Could not find endpoints for service "pzoo" in namespace "kafka". DNS records will be created once endpoints show up.
I0603 22:23:48.905981       1 dns.go:601] Could not find endpoints for service "mariadb" in namespace "mysql". DNS records will be created once endpoints show up.
I0603 22:23:48.906386       1 dns.go:601] Could not find endpoints for service "zoo" in namespace "kafka". DNS records will be created once endpoints show up.
I0603 22:23:49.392152       1 dns.go:222] Initialized services and endpoints from apiserver
I0603 22:23:49.392298       1 server.go:137] Setting up Healthz Handler (/readiness)
I0603 22:23:49.392319       1 server.go:142] Setting up cache handler (/cache)
I0603 22:23:49.392335       1 server.go:128] Status HTTP port 8081
```

I also noticed when enabling logging inside `dnsmasq` that queries are preformed but no reply is given. I have included a small snapshot of the log:

```
I0604 07:03:45.386985       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded prometheus-kube-state-metrics.metrics.svc.svc.cluster.local to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:45.419486       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[A] weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.weave.svc.cluster.local from 10.36.20.1
I0604 07:03:45.419666       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.weave.svc.cluster.local to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:45.421149       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[AAAA] weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.svc.cluster.local from 10.36.20.1
I0604 07:03:45.421266       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.svc.cluster.local to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:45.421333       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[A] weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.svc.cluster.local from 10.36.20.1
I0604 07:03:45.421437       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.svc.cluster.local to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:45.423253       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[A] weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.cluster.local from 10.36.20.1
I0604 07:03:45.423375       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.cluster.local to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:45.424088       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[AAAA] weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.europe-west4-a.c.suzuka.internal from 10.36.20.1
I0604 07:03:45.424270       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.europe-west4-a.c.suzuka.internal to 169.254.169.254
I0604 07:03:45.425873       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[A] weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.c.suzuka.internal from 10.36.20.1
I0604 07:03:45.426047       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.c.suzuka.internal to 169.254.169.254
I0604 07:03:45.427186       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[A] weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.google.internal from 10.36.20.1
I0604 07:03:45.427356       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local.google.internal to 169.254.169.254
I0604 07:03:45.432498       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[AAAA] weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local from 10.36.20.1
I0604 07:03:45.432665       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded weave-scope-app.weave.svc.cluster.local to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:45.679157       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[SRV] kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:45.679353       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:46.544879       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[PTR] 82.119.177.108.in-addr.arpa from 10.36.20.1
I0604 07:03:46.544929       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded 82.119.177.108.in-addr.arpa to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:47.613025       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] hits.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:47.613050       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config hits.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:47.613191       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] misses.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:47.613245       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config misses.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:47.613477       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] evictions.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:47.613547       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config evictions.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:47.613823       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] insertions.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:47.613879       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config insertions.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:47.614112       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] cachesize.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:47.614180       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config cachesize.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:49.544862       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[PTR] 25.121.18.104.in-addr.arpa from 10.36.20.1
I0604 07:03:49.545061       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded 25.121.18.104.in-addr.arpa to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:50.679458       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[SRV] kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:50.679606       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:52.614897       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] hits.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:52.614975       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config hits.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:52.615283       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] misses.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:52.615332       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config misses.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:52.615569       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] evictions.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:52.615615       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config evictions.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:52.615870       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] insertions.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:52.615915       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config insertions.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:52.616158       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] cachesize.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:52.616213       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config cachesize.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:55.281882       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[A] prometheus-kube-state-metrics.metrics.svc.metrics.svc.cluster.local from 10.36.20.8
I0604 07:03:55.282681       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded prometheus-kube-state-metrics.metrics.svc.metrics.svc.cluster.local to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:55.679869       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[SRV] kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:55.679903       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:57.616880       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] hits.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:57.616973       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config hits.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:57.617280       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] misses.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:57.617354       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config misses.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:57.617600       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] evictions.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:57.617656       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config evictions.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:57.617898       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] insertions.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:57.617957       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config insertions.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:57.618192       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[TXT] cachesize.bind from 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:57.618251       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: config cachesize.bind is <TXT>
I0604 07:03:57.976779       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: query[PTR] 10.240.39.10.in-addr.arpa from 10.36.20.21
I0604 07:03:57.976823       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: forwarded 10.240.39.10.in-addr.arpa to 127.0.0.1
I0604 07:03:57.977075       1 nanny.go:116] dnsmasq[11]: reply 10.39.240.10 is kube-dns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with KubeDNS. Din't find the root cause, but managed to fix by installing CoreDNS instead.

Since Kubernetes 1.11 [CoreDNS](https://github.com/coredns/deployment/tree/master/kubernetes) is used by default as a cluster DNS server, so I highly recommend to migrate to from KubeDNS to CoreDNS.

Consider this doc if you decide to proceed - 
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/coredns/#installing-kube-dns-instead-of-coredns-with-kubeadm

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I currently manages to solve the issue but will migrate KubeDNS to CoreDNS

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by upgrading both the master and node pools to the latest version of Kubernetes. Unfortunately was I not able to pinpoint the exact issue.